# How to send a http request using only the http crate?

Tags: http, rust, request, get, send

So I looked up the [http crate docs](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/index.html) and used `Request::builder()` to make a Request. However, as stupid as it sounds, I did not manage to find out how to send this request. Like what do I need to do? :p

There is a example code, but it cuts out the important part, the `send()` function:

```rs
use http::{Request, Response};

let mut request = Request::builder()
    .uri("https://www.rust-lang.org/")
    .header("User-Agent", "my-awesome-agent/1.0");

if needs_awesome_header() {
    request = request.header("Awesome", "yes");
}

let response = send(request.body(()).unwrap());

fn send(req: Request<()>) -> Response<()> {
    // ...
}
```

I already managed to send requests via hyper, following the [starter guide](https://hyper.rs/guides/1/client/basic/), but the http crate seems easier to understand to me...at least as long as I don't have to send my Request :p

Currently I have:

```rs
use http::{Request, Response, StatusCode};

fn main() {
    let request = Request::builder()
        .method("GET")
        .uri("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=system+overload")
        .header("artist", "smash stereo")
        .body(())
        .unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", request);

}
```

which outputs:

```
Request { method: GET, uri: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=system+overload, version: HTTP/1.1, headers: {"artist": "smash stereo"}, body: () }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The [crate documentation](https://docs.rs/http/1.0.0/http/index.html) itself states:

> You will notably *not* find an implementation of sending requests or spinning up a server in this crate. It’s intended that this crate is the “standard library” for HTTP clients and servers without dictating any particular implementation.

You can use `http` types with other libraries that *do* support sending requests like:

- [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) - most popular
- [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper) - lower level
- others ([isahc](https://crates.io/crates/isahc), [awc](https://crates.io/crates/awc), [ureq](https://crates.io/crates/ureq), etc.)